# Getting started with Jetson Tegra K1

Tags: linux

After working for a long time on my Arduino Due, I needed a better and more powerful prototyping platform for my future projects. For which, I have placed an order for NVIDIA Jetson Tegra K1 board which runs on linux and supports CUDA based development. Being a newbie to Linux, I have no idea where to start from and what to do for getting started with code execution on the Jetson board. Please suggest the initial steps required and from where can I get familiar to Linux environment...

Thank you

Comment: You should probably start by reading the documentation.

Comment: After getting familiarity, you may like to read my [survey paper on Deep learning on Jetson](https://www.academia.edu/38201537/A_Survey_on_Optimized_Implementation_of_Deep_Learning_Models_on_the_NVIDIA_Jetson_Platform) to learn features/challenges of Jetson and see how researchers have implemented and optimized their deep learning models on Jetson for various applications, like, self-driving cars, medical, image processing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search Nvidia site for their resources on Jetson TK1:  mailing list, IRC chat, toolchain etc.

https://developer.nvidia.com/linux-tegra-rel-21

and in github there are abundant development source codes:

https://www.google.com.sg/search?num=100&client=ubuntu&hs=AuY&channel=fs&q=site%3Agithub.com+jetson+tk1

And notice that the main CPU is ARM based.   And since cross-compilation is done on x86, and so perhaps you must learn all the cross-development knowhow as well.

As a newbie, I think you should first watch some video, read some unboxing experience, and start with GUI installation:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghqM8pzJZxg

http://jetsonhacks.com/2014/06/29/blog/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/548209/how-can-i-prevent-my-nvidia-jetson-tk1-from-automatically-booting-the-gui-black

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/788964/embedded-systems/jetson-tk1-gui-doesn-t-start-properly/

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/773182/embedded-systems/jetson-tk1-gui-not-loading-but-booting-properly-/

The "Grinch Kernel" mentioned above is here:

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/795734/embedded-systems/-customkernel-the-grinch-21-2-1-for-jetson-tk1/

Answer (score 2):

I found [eLinux.org's page on Jetson TK1](http://elinux.org/Jetson_TK1) very helpful. I especially recommend the [tutorials](http://elinux.org/Jetson_TK1#Tutorials_for_developing_with_Jetson_TK1).

Comment: Thanks. By the way, is it mandatory to connect the device to some sort of display unit or can it be used just by connecting to a network. P.S. I have a sony vaio and a broadband internet connection. Nothing else.

Comment: You can use it if it is connected to your local network. First time I used Jetson, it was just connected to LAN. In this usage mode, you can SSH into it, and then run your CUDA programs through the command line. However, when you use SSH, you are confined to the command line, and cannot interact with the GUI of Jetson. I recommend doing this after getting some experience with the GUI Linux environment.

Comment: Well. So connecting the Jetson to a monitor just provides access to its GUI, correct ??? ... (Sorry if this Q is too dumb)

Comment: On a superficial level yes, that looks like the only difference. However, for debugging CUDA programs with GUI for example (you probably won't need this for the time being), SSH is the superior way (since your computer runs the display, debugging doesn't hang the Jetson and you can debug your program with GUI).

Comment: Connection problems. Unable to access Jetson remotely. Command prompt says "No address associated with the hostname tegra-ubuntu"